# ggplot - prevent bar chart stacking

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a bar chart with an overlayed line graph measured on another y -axis.

I know this isn't necessarily the way you're supposed to do this, but this is what the customer wants.

I've got most of the way there but I'm having trouble finishing it off.

Here's the dataframe I'm working with:

```
  age      var1       var2  count
1  18 0.6553120 0.05554554 100.00
2  19 0.4869745 0.65048383  50.00
3  20 0.2142351 0.98546390  25.00
4  21 0.3888707 0.04171436  12.50
5  22 0.2707270 0.13346492   6.25
6  23 0.7637131 0.21246432   3.12
```

I then reshape it into long format:

```
   age  count composite_col    new_val
1   18 50.000          var1 0.65531200
2   19 25.000          var1 0.48697446
3   20 12.500          var1 0.21423509
4   21  6.250          var1 0.38887071
5   22  3.125          var1 0.27072698
6   23  1.560          var1 0.76371308
7   18 50.000          var2 0.05554554
8   19 25.000          var2 0.65048383
9   20 12.500          var2 0.98546390
10  21  6.250          var2 0.04171436
11  22  3.125          var2 0.13346492
12  23  1.560          var2 0.21246432


# mutate the counts so that we don't double count
df4 = df4 %>% mutate(count = count/(length(unique(composite_col))))
```

and then plot it with this monstrosity:

```
ggplot(data = df4) + theme_classic() + geom_col( aes(x=age, y=count),width=1.0, fill="red", colour="black")  + 
  geom_line( aes(x=age, y=new_val*100, colour=composite_col) ) + 
  scale_x_continuous( breaks = seq(18, 23,by = 1), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous("count", expand=c(0,0), sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name = "price", breaks = seq(0,2,by = 0.1) ))
```

Unfortunately it plots the counts of the age bins in a stacked fashion

[image: broken plot]

full code here:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1911)
df2 = data.frame(age = c(18,19,20,21,22,23), var1 = runif(6,0,1), var2 = runif(6,0,1), count = c(100,50,25,12.5,6.25,3.12) )
df2



df4 = gather(df2, "composite_col","new_val",c(var1,var2))
df4

# mutate the counts so that we don't double count
df4 = df4 %>% mutate(count = count/(length(unique(composite_col))))


ggplot(data = df4) + theme_classic() + geom_col( aes(x=age, y=count),width=1.0, fill="red", colour="black")  + 
  geom_line( aes(x=age, y=new_val*100, colour=composite_col) ) + 
  scale_x_continuous( breaks = seq(18, 23,by = 1), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous("count", expand=c(0,0), sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name = "price", breaks = seq(0,2,by = 0.1) ))
```

Comment: Try `geom_col(..., position='dodge')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you should use `position = "dodge"` parameter in geom_col

[image]